# How to Assign Property ID value to Variable in Wix file

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have a WiX include file with the following code:

```
<Property Id="DEPLOYTYPE" Value="[LA]" />
<?define DType= [DEPLOYTYPE]?>
```

Now in my Product tag in my WiX script, I'd like to set the `DELOYTYPE` Value to the value of DType, as it only takes localizable integers. Is there a way I can get my variable to be assigned the value of the property?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Preprocessor variables are calculated at compile time, while properties is a runtime Windows Installer concept. They serve two different purposes. Hence, the request doesn't make much sense. It would be great if you describe what you're trying to achieve eventually - I'm sure there's a way to accomplish that the right way.